# Use stored procedures for all entities including Xref / Link tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following convention that I apply in my Entity Framework model that will map all of my entities to use stored procedures:

```
modelBuilder.Types().Configure(cfg => cfg.MapToStoredProcedures());
```

This works great for the most part. The one case where it doesn't seem to work is when an entity has a many to many relationship without an entity for the Xref / Link table:

```
public class User
{
    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

This will create Insert, Update and Delete stored procs for the Users table and Roles table but it does not create Insert/Delete stored procedures for the UsersRoles table.

Is there any way to modify my convention so that it picks up these cases as well? I know I can manually wire it up, but I would prefer to avoid that if possible.